# Why isn't my Node.js/Express app returning records from my MongoDB database?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am trying to set up a RESTful API using MongoDB, Node.js, and Express. I'm new to all of these tools.

I’m having trouble with the connection to my MongoDB database (hosted on Atlas). My app seems to be connecting to the database, but always returns `[]` (status 200) when I query it with Postman.

On Atlas, my database is called DHP and my cluster is called dhammapada.

index.js file:

```
const express = require('express');

const app = express();

app.use(express.json());
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET');
    next();
});

// API routes
app.use('/api/dhp', require('./routes/api/verses'));

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server started on port ${PORT}`));
```

models/Verse.js file:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const verseSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    _id: {
        type: Number
    },
    verseNumber: {
        type: Number
    },
    text: {
        type: String
    }
},
{ collection: 'verses' }
);

module.exports = mongoose.model('verses', verseSchema);
```

routes/api/verses.js file:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const verses = require('../../models/Verse');

mongoose.connect('mongodb+srv://rgilmour70:*************@dhammapada.z7bsi.mongodb.net/DHP?retryWrites=true&w=majority', { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true });

const db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
db.once('open', () => {
    console.log('connected?');
});

// Gets all verses
// router.get('/', (req, res) => res.json(verses));
router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    verses.find({}, (err, result) => {
        if (err) {
            res.send(err);
        } else {
            res.send(result);
        }
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Finally, here's a screenshot from Postman showing my (lack of) results.

[image: Screenshot from Postman]

Any advice would be greatly appreciated. The MERN stack looks great, but this has had me stumped for two days now.

Comment: Will be a diffefence if you use `res.json(result)` instead of `res.send(result)`?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, @Anatoly, but that makes no difference. Still ```[]```

Comment: Do you have any data in the "verses" collection in DHP database?

Comment: Yes, @Rupjyoti, DHP.verses contains two entries.

Comment: It seems records are not available in your DB. Because I have tested your code on my local machine and it's working fine.

Comment: can you share your collection screenshot from robo3t or any other tool you use?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help, everyone. I really appreciate your taking the time to look over my code. Turns out the problem was that I didn't know the name of my own database. In the course of confirming that I did indeed have data in the database, I noticed that it is DBH.verses, not DHP.verses. (I don't know why I would have named it that--probably a typo.)